# Error when upload images larger than 1024px

Tags: uploads, plugin-wpml

I'm stuck on a problem with uploading files.

When I try to upload an image with 1024px or more, WordPress displays an error: Error sending. Try later.

After reloading the media page, the thumb of the file appears, but without showing the image. Testing the url of the file, I found that it is uploaded to the server.

**UPDATE**

The problem is related to WPML plugin. But apparently still there a solution.

https://wpml.org/forums/topic/images-not-added-to-media-library-on-upload-when-wpml-is-active-2/page/2/

Comment: The problem is not there. Somehow any plugin is interrupting your file upload. Disable all your plugin, switch back to default theme like TwentyFourteen, and `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in `wp-config.php` and observe what you get.

Comment: How large is the file, are there any errors in your javascript console? Are there any errors in your PHP log? What kind of image file and how large is it?

Comment: Guys, the problem is with WPML plugin. I'm trying to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have given the upload_max_filesize but you should also give post_max_size in your php.ini file..

```
 post_max_size = 32M
```

Comment: post_max_size was set to 50M. I enable wp_debug and some errors appears. I'm trying to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. What I did:

1. Update wpml to latest version (3.1.8.2)
2. On php.ini, change `memory_limit` to 128M
3. Increase `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` to 96M